# PDO query doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I can't do a query.

This is my code, where I connect to database and try to query.

EDIT :

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $query;


    function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host port=$this->port dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->password");
            echo "PDO connection object created";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    function setQuery($query) {
        $this->query = $query;
        $sth = $db->prepare($this->query);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        var_dump($result);
    }

}

$db = new DatabaseConnection('144.76.6.45','5432','eu','eu','eu123');
$db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM user');
```

This is my code, I don't have any errors, but still it doesn't work.....

Comment: Where $db comes from?

Comment: you should combine your classes into one or query should extend DatabaseConnection

Comment: Would you like some foie gras with that? But really, I know you are getting an error message. Have you just given up, or do you genuinely not know what to do?

Comment: i dont hava any errors, i really dont know how to realize this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of query you will want to fetch data after executing it. Take a look at [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php) and [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) methods.

```
$sth = $db->prepare($this->query);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

or use a loop and fetch row by row

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

**after your edit**:

Try to replace:

```
$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host port=$this->port dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->password");
```

with

```
$this->db = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host port=$this->port dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->password");
```

and then call `prepare` method on it: `$sth = $this->db->prepare($this->query);` instead of `$sth = $db->prepare($this->query);`

Comment: Hisamu gave you a clue, where did you initialize the `$db` on which you are calling prepare statement?

Comment: The `$conn` variable should be your `$db`. Also you should take a look at how to declare and access variables in PHP classes.

Comment: $db is an object of DatabaseCOnnection

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand, maybe you can paste the right code? So i can understand how it should work.

Comment: I edited the post. You are currently using `$conn` for PDO object, but are calling `prepare()` method on `$db` which is not initialized inside the scope of the class.

Comment: Anyway, it displays like array (var_dump) How should i work with PDO, to display it without array (like mysql_fetch_array does)?

Comment: Depending on which fetch function you used for `$result` you will get plain array with `fetch` (one element for each db field) or two-dimensional array with `fetchAll` (one for each row, and one for each db field). It is on you to 'extract' those elements from `$result` into variables you want. You can use standard array operations.

Comment: In this instance i should do like this - print $result['0']['eu_name']; how make that work like this print $result['eu_name'];

Comment: oh i can do that with fetch() not fetchall() Thanks again!

Comment: But it shows only one row. What if i want to show all rows in db?

Comment: You can use the while loop in combination with `fetch()` ( as in the example i provided in the answer).